# Displaying different content on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone

This is a two part question. I have a website where there is a simple link with information for a user to view and at the moment I only have an iOS app version of my product. What I would like to do is if the user were to view the link on an iOS device I would like to restrict some of the information visible to the user, encouraging them to download the iOS app to see the info but if they are on an android device I would like to display all necessary content to the user since we do not yet have an Android app available. My two questions are:

1) Is it possible to detect if a user is on an iOS device to limit how much they can view on the web page?

2) Is it bad practice to show different content to users based on their device?

By the way, security is not an issue here. To be more specific I have an events app and I want to hide the address field on the web page for iOS devices so they will more likely download the app to view it but I do not want to completely exclude Android users. Is this even worth my time? Should I just forget about Android users all together for now?

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad practice, everyone is displaying different content since you can't fit everything on phone devices. For example large tables.

You don't need javascript for this, you can do this with css only. Take a look at this example and try to implement it to your code.

HTML:

```
<a href="desktop/link" class="desktop">Link</a>
<a href="phone/link" class="phone">Link</a>
```

CSS

```
.desktop {
    display: block;
}

.phone {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    .phone {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I'm using the so called **media-queries** which you can find more information about [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

What this does is that the browser, both on initial render, resize, and rotate will display the rules within the media queries when the device windows width <= 768px. Those rules will override the previous.

Comment: What I'm mostly looking for is how I can display different content on an iPhone vs an Android device. This looks great for displaying different content on a desktop vs a mobile device but is there any way to detect if a user is using an iPhone?